# multiple properties for facebook feed publishing attachment

Tags: iphone, facebook

In the FBConnect.xproj, the feed string is as follows:

```
dialog.attachment = @"{\"name\":\"Facebook Connect for iPhone\",\"href\":\"http://developers.facebook.com/connect.php?tab=iphone\",\"caption\":\"Caption\",\"description\":\"Description\",\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\",\"src\":\"\",\"href\":\"http://developers.facebook.com/connect.php?tab=iphone/\"}],\"properties\":{\"another link\":{\"text\":\"Facebook home page\",\"href\":\"http://www.facebook.com\"}}}";
```

The 'properties' section looks like this:

```
...\"properties\":{\"another link\":{\"text\":\"Facebook home page\",\"href\":\"http://www.facebook.com\"}}}"
```

I want to know, how can I do multiple properties? There is no explicit example in the Facebook SDK documentation. For example, I'd like this to show up:

```
another link: Facebook home page 
yet another link: Twitter home page 
AND another link: ESPN home page
```

I can't seem to get the bracket/comma placement correctly...has anyone accomplished setting multiple properties? Please show me how! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can give multiple properties as here:
\"properties\":{\"another link\":{\"text\":\"Facebook home page\",\"href\":\"http://www.facebook.com\"}, \"yet another link\":{\"text\":\"Twitter home page\",\"href\":\"http://www.twitter.com\"}, \"AND another link\":{\"text\":\"ESPN home page\",\"href\":\"http://www.espn.com\"}}}"